# I can't figure out how to enable active state for a navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I can't set state the icons when clicked. This navigation bar was imported in different files.
Below is my code for navigation bar.

```css
.nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 88%;
  left: 12.5%;
  right: 12.5%;
  width: 75%;
  bottom: 25px;
  color: #70AD47;
  height: 80px;
  background: #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ccc;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.nav__link {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #444444;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  transition: background-color 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.nav__link:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.nav__link:active {
  color: #70AD47;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<nav class="nav">
  <a href="assignment.php" class="nav__link">
    <i class="material-icons nav__icon ">co_present</i>
    <span class="nav__text">Conferene Room</span>
  </a>
  <a href="archive.php" class="nav__link ">
    <i class="material-icons nav__icon">folder</i>
    <span class="nav__text">Archive</span>
  </a>
  <a href="classroom.php" class="nav__link">
    <i class="material-icons nav__icon">home</i>
    <span class="nav__text">Home</span>
  </a>
  <a href="assignment.php" class="nav__link">
    <i class="material-icons nav__icon">assignment</i>
    <span class="nav__text">Assignment</span>
  </a>
  <a href="discussion.php" class="nav__link">
    <i class="material-icons nav__icon">question_answer</i>
    <span class="nav__text">Defense Discussion</span>
  </a>
</nav>
```

Comment: You're talking about the colour which would be added when the `.nav__link:active` rule is applied, I assume? Well, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active says _"When using a mouse, "activation" typically starts when the user presses down the primary mouse button."_ . There's an example there too, for you to try out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer for doing this you need to use JavaScript or jQuery. I also commented on your `.nav__link:active` in your CSS since we don't use that.

**style10.css:**

```
.nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 88%;
    left: 12.5%;
    right: 12.5%;
    width: 75%;
    bottom: 25px;
    color: #70AD47;
    height: 80px;
    background: #eee;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ccc;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.nav__link {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
    min-width: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #444444;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    transition: background-color 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.nav__link:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

/*.nav__link:active {*/
/*    color: #70AD47;*/
/*}*/

.active {
    color: #70AD47;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Stack10</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style10.css">
</head>
<body>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<nav class="nav">
    <a href="#" class="nav__link active">
        <i class="material-icons nav__icon ">co_present</i>
        <span class="nav__text">Conferene Room</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="nav__link ">
        <i class="material-icons nav__icon">folder</i>
        <span class="nav__text">Archive</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="nav__link">
        <i class="material-icons nav__icon">home</i>
        <span class="nav__text">Home</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="nav__link">
        <i class="material-icons nav__icon">assignment</i>
        <span class="nav__text">Assignment</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="nav__link">
        <i class="material-icons nav__icon">question_answer</i>
        <span class="nav__text">Defense Discussion</span>
    </a>
</nav>

<script>

    var btnContainer = document.querySelector(".nav")

    var btns = btnContainer.querySelectorAll("a");

    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
        btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
            current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
            this.className += " active";
        });
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Demo here:

```js
    var btnContainer = document.querySelector(".nav")

    var btns = btnContainer.querySelectorAll("a");

    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
        btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
            current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
            this.className += " active";
        });
    }
```

```css
.nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 88%;
    left: 12.5%;
    right: 12.5%;
    width: 75%;
    bottom: 25px;
    color: #70AD47;
    height: 80px;
    background: #eee;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ccc;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.nav__link {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
    min-width: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #444444;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    transition: background-color 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.nav__link:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

/*.nav__link:active {*/
/*    color: #70AD47;*/
/*}*/

.active {
    color: #70AD47;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Stack10</title>

</head>
<body>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<nav class="nav">
    <a href="#" class="nav__link active">
        <i class="material-icons nav__icon ">co_present</i>
        <span class="nav__text">Conferene Room</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="nav__link ">
        <i class="material-icons nav__icon">folder</i>
        <span class="nav__text">Archive</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="nav__link">
        <i class="material-icons nav__icon">home</i>
        <span class="nav__text">Home</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="nav__link">
        <i class="material-icons nav__icon">assignment</i>
        <span class="nav__text">Assignment</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="nav__link">
        <i class="material-icons nav__icon">question_answer</i>
        <span class="nav__text">Defense Discussion</span>
    </a>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```